# Getting the inverse relation in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

There are schools and grades tables. Each school has by default 10 grades. But some schools have only some grades. So I created a table where I want to store the hidden grades for the school

Now I want to get the school grades, which are the default grades without the hidden ones.

This is db structure:

schools:

```
id
name
```

grades:

```
id

name
```

school_hidden_grades:

```
school_id

grade_id
```

Comment: What do you mean "laravel doesn't have relationship"? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Edit your question and change the question title

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like this :
**School Model**

```
    public function hiddenGrades( )
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Grade::class,'school_hidden_grades','school_id','grade_id');
    }

    public function grades( )
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Grade::class);
    }
```

and to get a schools hidden grades, you can simply do : `$school->hiddenGrades()->get();`

Comment: But I want to get un-hidden grades

Comment: @Behiry, if you want to hide a grade, then you should simply add a boolean column called : isHidden and set it to true/false on Grades table. then to get only visible grades of school: ``` $school->grades->where('isHidden', false); ```

Comment: This is true if there was one school, but each school has its hidden grades

Comment: @Behiry, you already have school_id in Grades table, which means that Grade belongs to one school

Comment: Sorry for that mistake, I removed it